# Geoserver integrated GWC not 'seeing' tiled layers

Tags: geoserver, ubuntu, tomcat

I am having trouble using Geoserver 2.4.1 integrated GWC, Ubuntu 13.04 and tomcat7

My data directory is set by setenv.sh with this string:

```
export CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -DGEOSERVER_DATA_DIR=/opt/gisdata/data"
```

When I check the /gwc folder in that directory, there are seeded folders and images. IE:

[image]

However, geoserver's tiled layers screen does not show any disk usage.

[image: Tile Layers Screenshot]

How can it be writing to the correct directory but not see those layer that it just wrote? Chmod 777 does not seem to help. Any advice, need more information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Computing disk usage for the entire cache directory is expensive so there's a module in GWC called Disk Quota which maintains a running total for each layer as tiles are added and removed. By default, Disk Quota is turned off, which results in the 0 values you see. Turn on DiskQuota (in the sidebar under "Tile Caching") and it will start showing the correct values.  It will compute the initial value from the disk so it will show already cached usage.

Comment: Selected as correct answer because it sounds like you know. When I enabled disk quota geoserver threw up an exception that, on the surface, looks like it ran out of memory. I'm on a vps with 1k ram. I will look into it tomorrow, when I get to the office.